# error on local PHP server: localhost refused to connect

Tags: php

I am trying to run a development server on my Mac. I have been able to do so before with no issues. I'm not aware of any changes I've made, but now the server starts, but I'm unable to access it from a browser:

```
❯❯❯ php -S localhost:8000                                      ⏎
PHP 5.6.30 Development Server started at Mon Oct 16 18:06:16 2017
Listening on http://localhost:8000
```

I get this message from the browser:

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

No noise from the server process at the command line. 
My /etc/hosts file has the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried the IP? please add the mac tag as well

Comment: when I start the server using the IP instead of localhost it does work - `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` does work. I guess I can work with this, but I still don't know what's happening with localhost

Comment: I do have a bunch of other names mapped to 127.0.0.1, but /etc/hosts only contains the one mention of localhost

Comment: may to flush the DNS cache `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` ps i dont do mac, so

Comment: so it works with any other name I have mapped to 127.0.0.1, only localhost gives me trouble. Is there something that overrides the mappings in /etc/hosts. Maybe there's another mapping for localhost somewhere else?